# How to modify csv headers with powershell when there are no rows?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a PowerShell script that reads the CSV file, combines two rows into one based on condition, modifies column names, and exports a new CSV file. The problem is that script isn't working when CSV file has no rows although column names still need to be modified. I don't really know Powershell so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$csv = import-csv "<CSVFilePath>" 

$fars = @()
$nears = @()
$combined = @()

foreach($line in $csv){
    if(<CONDITION>) {
        $fars += $line
    } else {
        $nears += $line
    } 
} 

foreach($far in $fars){
    foreach($near in $nears) {
        if(<CONDITION>)  {
        
            $o = New-Object -Type PSObject 

            $far.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
                $far_field = $_.Name + " FAR"
                $o | Add-Member -Name $far_field -Type NoteProperty -Value $_.Value                          
             }

            $near.PSObject.Properties| ForEach-Object {ls
                $near_field = $_.Name + " NEAR"
                $o | Add-Member -Name $near_field -Type NoteProperty -Value $_.Value
            }
            $combined += $o
        }
    }
}

$combined | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"', ""}  | out-file "<CSVFilePath>" -fo -en ascii
```

Comment: When you import a csv file that contains only a header line, the result is `$null`, so you could check `$csv = import-csv  "<CSVFilePath>"; if (!$csv) { <# re-read the file with Get-Content and alter the headers #> } else { <# your code here #> }`

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!